# Could the dictionary of operations be eliminated from this generalized Set definition?

Tags: f#, set, polymorphism, comparison, discriminated-union

I am trying to generalize the concept of a `Set` in `F#`. Among other things I want to define sets using inequalities. This would help me simplifying some sections of my code. So I created a type `MySet` as follows:

```
type Comparison = | GE
                  | GT
                  | LE
                  | LT
                  | EQ

type ComparisonOps<'t> = { gt: 't->'t->bool
                           ge: 't->'t->bool
                           eq: 't->'t->bool
                           le: 't->'t->bool
                           lt: 't->'t->bool }

type MySet<'t when 't : comparison> =
    | List of list<'t>
    | Sequence of seq<'t>
    | Array of 't []
    | String of string
    | Set of Set<'t>
    | Compare of (ComparisonOps<'t>*Comparison*'t)
```

Note: I intend to make `MySet` recursive later, allowing for unions and intersections, but for the purposes of this question this is not necessary.

The whole point of the new `MySet` type is to allow checking if elements of different types belong to sets of different cases. This is implemented by this function:

```
let elementOf<'t when 't : comparison> (st: MySet<'t>) (x: 't) : bool =
    match st with
    | List xs    -> List.contains x xs   
    | Sequence s -> Seq.contains x s
    | Array a    -> Array.contains x a
    | Set st     -> Set.contains x st
    | String str -> match box str with
                    | :? string as s -> match box x with
                                        | :? string as z -> s.Contains z
                                        | _ -> false
                    | _ -> false
    | Compare (comp: ComparisonOps<'t>*Comparison*'t) ->
        let compOps, cmp, y = comp
        match cmp with
        | GT -> compOps.gt x y
        | GE -> compOps.ge x y
        | EQ -> compOps.eq x y
        | LE -> compOps.le x y
        | LT -> compOps.lt x y
```

Note: I also plan to generalize `elementOf` allowing for function application, but again this is not needed here.

The function works:

```
let myStringSet = MySet.String("XYZ")
let strb = "X" |> elementOf<string> myStringSet
printfn "strb = %b" strb // strb = true

let myListSet = MySet.List([0..10])
let listb = 5 |> elementOf<int> myListSet
printfn "listb = %b" listb // listb = true

let myCompSet = MySet.Compare((ComparisonFloat, GT, 0.0))
let compb = -1.0 |> elementOf<float> myCompSet
printfn "compb = %b" compb // compb = false

let myCompSet2 = MySet.Compare((ComparisonString, LT, "XYZ"))
let compb2 = "XA" |> elementOf<string> myCompSet2
printfn "compb2 = %b" compb2 // compb2 = true
```

That is great, but I wonder if I really need to create the dictionary of operations `ComparisonOps`, since operations like `<` are polymorphic on the types int, float and string anyway.

Eliminating `ComparisonOps` could considerably simplify the code. Is that possible?

Comment: The triple of `(ComparisonOps<'t>*Comparison*'t)` is really just an overcomplicated way of encoding the membership test function `'t -> bool`

Comment: I agree. So what would be a not-overcomplicated way of encoding the membership test function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Its looking strangely overcomplicated

Comment: By the way, the `String` case looks really weird; it appears that `String("abc")` has the following elements: `[""; "a"; "b"; "c"; "ab"; "bc"; "abc"]`.  Is this really the intended behavior?  I would have expected a string to contain characters, not substrings.

Comment: Yes, but I will need to deal with both cases, the substring and the character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Fyodor Soikin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180286/fyodor-soikin) notes, it sounds like maybe what you want is to define a set as all elements satisfying a predicate:

```
type MySet<'t> = | MySet of ('t -> bool)
```

Then set operations are easy to define:

```
let intersect (MySet p1) (MySet p2) = MySet(fun t -> p1 t && p2 t)
```

And all of your specific constructors can just be turned into simple functions:

```
let ofList l = MySet(fun t -> List.contains t l)
let lt x = MySet(fun t -> t < x)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed. Actually I dropped the sets to work only with predicates.